# How do I write schema to validate an element with the same name having different content?

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

How do I write schema (XSD1.0) to validate an element with the same name having different content?  (Is it possible?  Initial investigation seems to suggest this violates "Element Declaration Consistency", but I could be wrong on this.)

The snippets below illustrate what I need - essentially, I can have an occurrence of "ParentTag" (which is deeply nested in my document), and it can contain any of the contents defined in the 3 variants below.  I should note that "ParentTag" is seen only once under an ancestor element, so only one variant is encountered in a particular branch of the tree.

I am a consumer of the XML, not a generator, and have no ability to change the source XML.  It seems that I want to do something similar to "choice" (or maybe "union"?), but this definition has eluded me.

As a fallback (ugly kludge), it seems that the best I have been able to do is to use 'any' and then rely on my consuming application code (which I do control) to "complete" the validation as it parses the XML.

Variant 1:

```
<ParentTag>
    <!-- '<value>' can repeat -->
    <value>some value</value>  <!--(type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded")-->
</ParentTag>
```

Variant 2:

```
<ParentTag>
    <!-- Note: order of subelements not guaranteed: 'all', not 'sequence' -->
    <minValue>v1</minValue>   <!--(type="xsd:int" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1")-->
    <maxValue>v2</maxValue>   <!--(type="xsd:int" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1")-->
</ParentTag>
```

Variant 3:

```
<ParentTag>
    <specialValue>special value</specialValue> <!--(type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1")-->
</ParentTag>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, in XSD 1.0, to have different content models requires different element names<sup>1</sup>.  This is not that onerous of a requirement as same names really should imply sameness.

XSD 1.1 allows type to vary per attribute values ([Conditional Type Assignment](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/#cTypeAlternative)).  XSD 1.1 also has assertions, which provide additional type specification flexibility.

Given that you've said that you're stuck with this (bad) XML design, your options are limited and unsatisfying.  If you don't want to the `xsd:any` route, you could leverage `xs:choice` and specify each possible content model in that manner.

<sup><sub>1. Exceptions: same local names differentiated via namespaces or same names differentiated via hierarchical heritage (as [Michael Kay mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50069669/290085)) can have different content models.</sub></sup>

Comment: Yeah, XSD1.1 Conditional Type Assignment and assert are exactly what I need.  But, for now, I'm stuck using a particular tool that doesn't support 1.1.  (Thanks for mentioning the "choice" option as an alternative.  IMO, it's even uglier than the "any" approach. Even so, unfortunately, this validator library implementation also has a bug that makes "choice" non-viable, so it really wasn't an option for me anyways.  Such is the life of a developer in the trenches... *sigh*)

Answer (score 0):

You say "only one variant is encountered in a particular branch of the tree."

It's possible to have different content models for ParentTag if the different kinds of ParentTag appear in different contexts. For example:

```
<xs:element name="Customer">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
       <xs:element name="Address">
          <xs:complexType>
             <xs:element name="Street" type="xs:string"/>
             <xs:element name="City" type="xs:string"/>
          </xs:complexType>
       </xs:element>
   </xs:sequence>
 </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="Supplier">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
       <xs:element name="Address">
          <xs:complexType>
             <xs:element name="Road" type="xs:string"/>
             <xs:element name="Town" type="xs:string"/>
          </xs:complexType>
       </xs:element>
   </xs:sequence>
 </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

So a supplier address is something quite different from a customer address.

Usually the distinctions are more subtle than this: for example in the schema for the XML representation of JSON in the XPath 3.1 spec, an `<array>` contained within a `<map>` has a slightly different content model from an `<array>` appearing anywhere else.

Comment: Perhaps my wording in the original question is misleading or incomplete - by "tree" and "branch", I am referring to the structure of the XML itself, not any form of an AST.  Your answer assumes that the branches are distinguishable by an ancestor element tag ("Customer" and "Supplier" in your example), but this is not the case in my situation.  In fact, the contents of the variant "parent" element is determined according to the value of another tag that is a sibling of the "parent" element.  (So XSD1.1 "Conditional Type Assignment", as mentioned in kjhughes' answer applies.)